# Why does super only has a subset of class attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

Suppose I use `super` outside a class. I can do this.

```
super(int, 1).__str__ # <method-wrapper '__str__' of int object at 0x000000005E29C6B0>
```

But I cannot do this

```
super(int, 1).__float__ # raises an AttributeError
```

With more generality, I can check all methods that `1` has but not the `super(int, 1)` object.

```
set(dir(1)) - set(dir(super(int,1)))
```

This outputs a set of over forty attributes specific to `1`, namely `__round__`, `__float__` or `real` to name only a few.

What causes this behaviour of `super` and/or what is different about those methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `super(int, 1).__float__`, you're asking for the method `int.__float__` overrides. There isn't one.

Comment: @Olivier: If you want to ask a different question, post a new question. Don't edit an existing question to transform it into something completely different.